# How do I count Rows that have common domain with another table using query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2016, and in the SQL editor, I would like to make a query that counts the number of vendors whose state is the same state as customers and lists each customer, with the number of vendors who are in the same state as the customer.

I have two relevant tables, **Vendor_T** and **Customer_T**, and there are no relationships between them, However, they both have State Attributes that show which of the United States the vendor or customer is in.

So far I have some non-working code that I think might help me get what I need, **The pseudo code is in the angle brackets[]**

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, [COUNT(VendorID) Which has V.VendorState=C.CustomerState]
FROM Vendor_T V, Customer_T C
GROUP BY C.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join using the state column:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, COUNT(V.VendorID) 
FROM Vendor_T V join Customer_T C ON V.VendorState=C.CustomerState
GROUP BY C.CustomerName
```

Comment: My code worked when I used yours, except I had to change "JOIN" to "INNER JOIN"  Thanks, I was making the problem more complicated than it had to be.